Is $\lim_{h\to 0}\sin(h)\sin(\frac{1}{h})$ equal to zero, or does it not exist?
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\sin(h)\sin\left(\frac{1}{h}\right)$$
I’m trying to figure out if the answer to this is 0, because:
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\sin(h)\sin\left(\frac{1}{h}\right) = \lim_{h\to 0}\sin(h)\times \lim_{h\to 0}\sin\left(\frac{1}{h}\right) = 0\times \text{undefined} = 0$$
Or if the limit is undefined because:
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\sin(h)\sin\left(\frac{1}{h}\right) = \lim_{h\to 0}\sin(h)\times \lim_{h\to 0}\sin\left(\frac{1}{h}\right) = 0\times \text{undefined} = \text{undefined}$$
Or if I am completely wrong altogether.
Thank you!

Hi, welcome to Math SE. Hint: squeeze $\sin h\sin\frac1h$ between $\pm\sin h$.

Even if it is undefined, $\underset{h\to 0}{\lim},\sin\left(\frac{1}{h}\right)$ is bounded between $-1$ and $1$.

Duplicate target found with Approach0

Thank you for the welcome! and thanks for the tip too I understand it now.
